# Is there any way to check whether the class has attribute in PHP?

Tags: php

All

I wrote a class like this :

```
class A {
    private $attr01 = null;

    function __set( $name, $value ) {
        if ( isset($this->attr01) ) {
            $this->attr01 = $value;
        }
        else {
            ;// something else
        }
    }
}
```

but, in the manual, that isset returns false if the value is null, so, is there any way to check whether the attribute exists or not ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use the [`property_exists`](http://php.net/property_exists) function:

> `property_exists` — Checks if the object or class has a property

```
function __set( $name, $value ) {
    $prop = 'attr01';
    if (property_exists($this, $prop)) {
        $this->$prop = $value;
    }
    else {
        ;// something else
    }
}
```